# Замена текста jQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Как можно заменить пробел на плюс? Есть `str_replace` в jQuery?

```
var blabla='бла бла';
```

в

```
var blabla='бла+бла';
```

я это делаю, чтобы потом в строку браузера вставить

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'http://' + window.location.host + '/ ' + blabla);
```

но получается в строке браузера вместо пробелов %20.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Ну так вот можно

```
    var blabla='бла бла';
    blabla.replace(" ","+");
//    или
    blabla.replace("/s","+"); // так правильнее, но заменит только один пробел на символ + так что если в строке друг за другом идет более 1 пробела, то нужно по другому заменять
```

Comment: Так заменит все

    blabla.replace(/\s/g,'+'); //правда еще отtrimить нужно перед этим

Comment: ну да, ну в вопросе было про один пробел, я и написал про один, про остальные хотелось бы чтобы хоть кто-то думать научился а не копипастил ответы.